# Deleted jars while migrating MobileFirst project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am trying to migrate MobileFirst project from 6.0 to 7.1.
When I loaded the project into MobileFirst Studio, I noticed that these jars (`commons-codec.jar, jackson-core-asl.jar, jackson-mapper-asl.jar, gcm.jar, cordova_plugins.jar`) automatically get deleted from `apps/MyWLApp/android/native/libs`. Why did that happen?
Also found that I have to delete `httpcore-4.4.jar` from `apps/MyWLApp/android/native/libs`, in order for the android app to be built without errors.
If not deleted, I got this error:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Header;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Header;
```

Is it safe to have all those jars deleted? or should I find another updated version of them to work with MobileFirst 7.1?

Is there any official document declaring the list of deprecated/incompatible jars with MobileFirst 7.1?
I found this message in the MF Studio console:

> It is recommended to update the code according to the Information
>   Center article "Migrating Application Classes"

But I failed to find that article anywhere on the internet!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight 6.0 is very old. A lot has changed between 6.0 and 7.1. It seems that the files you've mentioned are removed as part of the migration process the Studio is performing, so that should be fine, especially since you say that only in this way the app is compiled. And if the app is compiled and in working shape then...

There is no complete list. There are a lot of jars out there.

The document for migrating applications to MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 is available here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/topics/t_upgrading.html

Comment: As you said, as the project compiled with no errors I am assuming that I am fine. But just want to make sure that I am on the correct path & that there is nothing gonna break down on runtime.
I have actually read the links you provided, but it mention nothing about deleted jars.

Comment: This is the process that all migrated apps go through.